# Can't get data from file in C++

Tags: c++, file, text, file-io, text-files

I've been trying to read a text file with a loop.  But for some reason, it never seems to get the integer values correct.  I always end up with garbage values.

```
while(!file.eof())  // I've also tried other variations of this while loop, none of which worked either
    {
        // ifstream, string, char, string, int
        file >> name >> sex >> data >> score;  
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
        if (sex == 'F')
        {
            femaleAverage += score;
            femaleCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            maleAverage += score;
            maleCount++;
        }

        if (data.compare("CC"))
        {
            comAverage += score;
            comCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            uniAverage += score;
            uniCount++;
        }
    }
```

Here is what the text file looks like:

```
Bailey           M CC 68
Harrison         F CC 71
Grant            M UN 75
Peterson         F UN 69
Hsu              M UN 79
Bowles           M CC 75
Anderson         F UN 64
Nguyen           F CC 68
Sharp            F CC 75
Jones            M UN 75
McMillan         F UN 80
Gabriel          F UN 62
```

Comment: and what does your output look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `if` statements, it looks like `sex` is declared as `char` rather than `char*` or `std::string`. When you use `file >> sex`, it read the next character from the file into variable, *without skipping over whitespace* like it does for strings or numbers. As a result, `sex` gets the first space after the name, then it reads the sex field of the file into `data` and tries to read the data field into `score`.

You can use the [`std::skipws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/skipws/) value to skip over whitespace before reading it.

You also shouldn't use `while (!file.feof())`, see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

So the code should look like:

```
while (file >> name >> std::skipws >> sex >> data >> score) {
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    if (sex == 'F')
    {
        femaleAverage += score;
        femaleCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        maleAverage += score;
        maleCount++;
    }

    if (data.compare("CC"))
    {
        comAverage += score;
        comCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        uniAverage += score;
        uniCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you solved one problem.  Turns out that wasn't what was causing my issue.  Still, thanks anyway.

Comment: @ryan What was the problem?